# SUM multiple Count and Group by

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I need a count of total actions id (calls, meetings and tasks) group by Username and the name Accounts

I try this, but the total isn't correct

```
SELECT count(calls.id) + count(meetings.id) + count(tasks.id) AS 'total', users.user_name AS 'name', GROUP_CONCAT(accounts.name) AS 'accounts' 
FROM accounts, calls, users, meetings, tasks
WHERE accounts.id = calls.parent_id 
AND calls.assigned_user_id = users.id
AND accounts.id = meetings.parent_id
AND meetings.assigned_user_id = users.id
AND accounts.id = tasks.parent_id
AND tasks.assigned_user_id = users.id
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and expected output?

Comment: GROUP BY name,accounts.name ?

Comment: How is the total not correct? Can you show us sample data, and what results you're getting?

Comment: The database is Sugar CRM CE

Comment: Is it because count(calls.id) is counting all the ids in the calls table as you did not limit the table search. If you want to limit the search, use table join instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the benefit of having representative data to test with, my guess would be that the joining 5 tables has multiplied the rows and hence the totals are incorrect due to that. Using DISTINCT inside the COUNT() might help, e.g.

```
SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT calls.id) 
    + COUNT(DISTINCT meetings.id) 
    + COUNT(DISTINCT tasks.id) AS 'total'
    , users.user_name AS 'name'
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT accounts.name) AS 'accounts'
FROM accounts
      INNER JOIN calls ON accounts.id = calls.parent_id
      INNER JOIN users ON calls.assigned_user_id = users.id
      INNER JOIN meetings ON accounts.id = meetings.parent_id
                  AND meetings.assigned_user_id = users.id
      INNER JOIN tasks ON accounts.id = tasks.parent_id
                  AND tasks.assigned_user_id = users.id
GROUP BY
      users.user_name
;
```

Note I have swapped the old way of joining through the where clause for a more modern approach, you really should join in.

Another possibility is that your counts are incorrect because you are using INNER JOINS which require the existence of data in both tables for rows to be returned. So maybe you need some LEFT OUTER JOINs instead.

```
SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT calls.id) 
    + COUNT(DISTINCT meetings.id) 
    + COUNT(DISTINCT tasks.id) AS 'total'
    , users.user_name AS 'name'
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT accounts.name) AS 'accounts'
FROM accounts
      LEFT OUTER JOIN calls ON accounts.id = calls.parent_id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON calls.assigned_user_id = users.id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN meetings ON accounts.id = meetings.parent_id
                  AND meetings.assigned_user_id = users.id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks ON accounts.id = tasks.parent_id
                  AND tasks.assigned_user_id = users.id
GROUP BY
      users.user_name
;
```

The final query might be a mixture of joins, some INNER and some LEFT.

Comment: Natronic has let me know it was the LEFT JOIN version seen above which worked.

Comment: Yes, the LEFT JOIN version

Answer (score 0):

```
`SELECT COUNT(calls.id) + COUNT(meetings.id) + COUNT(tasks.id) AS total, GROUP_CONCAT(users.user_name) AS name, GROUP_CONCAT(accounts.name) AS accounts
FROM accounts JOIN calls ON (accounts.id = calls.parent_id) 
JOIN users ON (calls.assigned_user_id = users.id) 
JOIN meetings ON (meetings.assigned_user_id = users.id) 
JOIN tasks ON (accounts.id = tasks.parent_id and tasks.assigned_user_id = users.id) 
GROUP BY users.user_name, accounts.name`
```